# 1-port VNA quality factor measurement

Tags: vna, resonator, quality

I am using an Anritsu VNA (MS2034B) to obtain the LINEAR MAGNITUDE and PHASE of S11 via a calibrated 1-port measurement. The DUT is an inductively coupled RLC resonator (schematic below). However, I don't really know how to extract the quality factor from the resonant dips. Can I do a 3dB bandwidth method? Or is it a 1/sqrt(2) method given that I have linear magnitude data?

[image]

Comment: What is exactly your DUT? I don't understand what it is? What is your measured S11 (picture) ?